# Capture Google Analytics data from Charles Proxy using automation

Tags: java, proxy

Currently we are using Charles Proxy to capture Google Analytics data for our web site testing. Each page we navigate will have a POST created and request data as shown in the attached screenshot. We use this to compare to each web page. We are now trying to automate this process and are looking for guidance on how to capture this data (name/value) using our automated script (Java). Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[image: screenshot]

Thanks!

Matt

Comment: Use browsermob proxy instead. It is pure Java proxy that can be used embedded.